# The number of active nuclei left after a half life has passed

Tags: radioactivity

This is the given statement:
A radioactive substance has a half life of 1 hour. Therefore if two nuclei of the substance are present initially, after 1 hour only one will remain undissociated.

I think this is a correct statement but my textbook says it's wrong. I don't understand how, because this statement obeys the Rutherford Soddy Law. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Of course there is also the probabilistic aspect that you need to take into account.

Answer (score 2):

The half life concerns the probability that a nucleus will decay. Therefore there is a 25% probability that no decay will take place, 50% probability that one will decay and 25% probability that both will decay. Only when you have a large number of particles, it becomes statistically likely that close to half of them will decay.